# how to read files in postgresql data directory

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How to read a file in pgsql/data/base/16384 directory in postgresql.
these files similar to binary file or dat file.
I try to import it in a specific table using pgAdmin, but I got error like this:
[see the below picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBqKo.png)

Also I try to Restore whole database using tar file but i got "no header for toc.dat" when restoring with pgadmin.

Is there any way to read files in data/base/16384 in postgresql?

Thank to All my friend.

Comment: Those are the actual database files. Only the Postgres server can (and should) read them. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I setup postgres service, I want to retrieve table data.

Comment: You don't access files in a server based database. You use a SQL client (e.g. `psql` or pgAdmin), connect to the server and then run the appropriate [SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-sql.html) to retrieve the data. (Btw: the short form of the product name is Postgres - **not** "Postgre")

Comment: yeah,Thank you, but how can I read this using sql commands?
or using pgAdmin?
specifically 11779.dat file in Data/base/16384 How can I read this?

Comment: You run `select` statements for the table to which that file maps.

Comment: Ok but how to use select in this specific condition.
I want to select table names in OID.
 when i execute below query, it is succefull but returned NULL.

select datname from pg_database where oid = 16384;

whenever in fact this not NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with pgAdmin:

```
select datname from pg_database where oid = 16384;
--connect to the database from return of above
select relname from pg_class where relfilenode = 11779;
--select * from <return of above>
```

Comment: I execute this query with succeful result, but no data have been shown!
what is datname and relname in query?
Thank you my Friend.

Comment: tbale, column names

Comment: How can i find other table name and column name?

Comment: And how can i know what table in a specific file?(if i choose other file like 11757, what table and column should i write?)

Comment: please read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html or at least answered post above

Comment: I am very Thankful my dear Friend.